# Sequelize - Running sync is building multiple versions of tables that had different file names with FK and initialised values in different versions

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have changed the names of my models to the same as they were in defined as I advised to do this to get my "include" returns working correctly. Since then despite both my const name and define name being the exact same, I am getting multiple tables created for the same model on  PGadmin. This has now caused me problems as my initialised values and foreign keys are appearing on different tables.

Is this a common problem? Would I best changing back to the old naming structure? I had previously just put an s on the end of the define models however my "include" statements didn't return anything when I entered them all in my index.js/model file.

Could this be something to do with the way my pgAdmin is connected? as the connection goes back to last month I thought there might be old data somewhere. I had previously thought that Sequelize sync just wiped the folder and started again with the models / constraints / initialised values in my IDE.

[image]

I am also getting errors like the below one although my server hasn't crashed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason pgAdmin likes the plural names of my models and It worked better when I named them in the singular and plural form. In the case of where I "defined" them I used the plural names and in cases where I am doing associations like "model.examples" I used the version it was defined in.

I have now got my associations working with with Postman API's and the foreign key values are being pulled correctly.

I'm still not sure why the old names were being generated but It may have had something to do with the connection to my IDE pulling older syncs that I had generated previously.